# How to post a file as multipart/form-data in Kotlin?

Tags: python, http, post, kotlin, request

How to upload file via sending a post request with a path to the file in Kotlin?

This is what I did in Python, it manage to work, it is plain and simple.

```
import requests

//file that I want to upload
path = 'download/special.db'

files = {'file': open(path, 'rb')}

r = requests.post('http://myurl/newfile/Upload', files=files)

print (r.text)
```

This code work and manage to print the response

I need to write one version for my Android app, is it possible to write something similar in Kotlin? send a post request and attach a `files=files` to my request and send. The problem, what is the kotlin equivalentof that? is it possible to write everything on one activity?

what should I write for `files = {'file': open(path, 'rb')}` in kotlin?

Search online, most of the method is use Retrofit, which is too complicated.